# Distribution of Product of Arbitrary Number of Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

Suppose $X_i\sim f_{X_i}(x)$, with each $X_i$ independent and identically distributed for some arbitrary probability density function $f_{X_i}(x)$.  Given this information, and this information only, define the new random variable:

$$Y=\prod_{i=1}^nX_i$$

What is the distribution of $Y$?  Particularly, what is its probability density function?  If each $X_i$ is a discrete random variable, what's the analog?  If there's no easy way to obtain $f_Y(y)$, is there a way to get the moment generating function of $Y$ instead?

Comment: It is quite a job. If the $X_i$ are positive a.s. then you can start finding the distribution of $\ln X_i$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n\ln X_i$ by means of convolution and then $e^{\sum_{i=1}^n\ln X_i}$.

Comment: If there was a general answer, there won't be papers devoted to finding distributions of product of random variables having specific distributions!